# Creating a user-defined total with grand_summary_rows()

Tags: r

I have a table that looks like this:

```
  category family       amount
  <chr>    <chr>        <chr> 
1 SALES    ONLINE SALES 47    
2 SALES    IN STORE     72    
3 COGS     LABOR        28    
4 COGS     TAXES        35    
5 COGS     WORKERS COMP 24    
6 COGS     BENEFITS     33    
7 EXPENSE  AUTOMOBILE   44    
8 EXPENSE  RENT         12    
9 EXPENSE  TELEPHONE    26
```

I am trying to create a gt table from this so I have created this code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

category <- c(rep("SALES",2),
              rep("COGS", 4),
              rep("EXPENSE",3)
)
family <- c("ONLINE SALES","IN STORE","LABOR","TAXES","WORKERS COMP","BENEFITS",
            "AUTOMOBILE", "RENT","TELEPHONE")

amount <- c(47,72,28,35,24,33,44,12,26)


output <- as_tibble(cbind(category,family,amount)) %>% 
    mutate(amount= as.numeric(amount)) %>% 
    gt(rowname_col = 'family',
       groupname_col = 'category') %>% 
    row_group_order(c("SALES","COGS", "EXPENSE")) %>% 
    summary_rows(groups = TRUE,
                 columns = 'amount',
                 fns = list(
                     Total = ~sum(.,na.rm = TRUE)
                 ))
output
```

How do you get the overall total of `SALES-COGS-EXPENSE` using the  `grand_summary_rows()` function while all of the amounts are still positive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I have correctly understood your request you can use the code below:

```
output2 <- as_tibble(cbind(category,family,amount)) %>% 
           mutate(amount= as.numeric(amount)) %>% 
           gt(rowname_col = 'family', groupname_col = 'category') %>%
           summary_rows(groups = TRUE,
             columns = 'amount',
             fns = list(
             Total = ~sum(.,na.rm = TRUE)
             )) %>%  
           grand_summary_rows(
             columns = c("family","category","amount"),
             fns = list(
             "Grand Total" = ~sum(.,na.rm = TRUE)),
             formatter = fmt_number,
             use_seps = FALSE
            )

output2
```

[image]

**################### EDIT ###################**

The only way I found from the documentation is to create a custom aggregation function. Here's the full working example with the output printscreen.

```
customFunc <- function(data) {

  salesSum <- sum(subset(data$`_data`[,c("amount")], category == 'SALES'))
  cogsSum <- sum(subset(data$`_data`[,c("amount")], category == 'COGS'))
  expenseSum <- sum(subset(data$`_data`[,c("amount")], category == 'EXPENSE'))

  return (salesSum - cogsSum - expenseSum)

}

data <- as_tibble(cbind(category,family,amount)) %>% 
  mutate(amount= as.numeric(amount)) %>% 
  gt(rowname_col = 'family', groupname_col = 'category')

output3 <- data %>%
  summary_rows(groups = TRUE,
               columns = 'amount',
               fns = list(
                 Total = ~sum(.,na.rm = TRUE)
               )) %>%  
  grand_summary_rows(
    columns = c("family","category","amount"),
    fns = list(
      "Grand Total" = ~customFunc(data)),
    formatter = fmt_number,
    use_seps = FALSE
  )

output3
```

[image]

Comment: This isn't exactly what I am looking for. I want the the `grand_summary_rows()` to have a function that is:
`Total = subtotal(SALES) - subtotal(COGS) - subtotal(EXPENSES)`
So in this case `Total = -83.`

I hope this brings some clarification.

Comment: Updated (I kept the previous response should it be useful for someone else)